# Meteor check if a username exist in user collection

Tags: meteor

This Meteor client code attempts to check if a username exist in the users collection, It has been verified that it is but the `if` condition is evaluating to false. What am I doing wrong? How to fix it? Thanks

```
if (Session.get('taskSelected') == 'login') {
    var username = inputDoc[0].value + '-' + inputDoc[1].value;
    if (Meteor.users.findOne({username: username})) {
      console.log('found it in');
    }
}
```

**edit**

After the answer I realised that I do have this publish code in the server file

```
Meteor.publish('users', function () {
    if (this.userId) {
      return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
    }
 });
```

Comment: Do you realize I have had to remove the mongodb tag from every single question you have asked? As a future hint, if you are not actually asking about mongodb query syntax or specific methods `.find()` `.update()` etc, then your question is not about this and is just a "meteor" question only. Please stop using the tag unless the question is actually about the topics as mentioned.

Comment: @BlakesSeven  Oh, Sorry, I thought the problem maybe anywhere in the code which could be in the second if condition being evaluated which has a mongo findOne method and Meteor and Mongo are so connected that I should include both tags, But "now point taken"I will only use meteor in future which makes it easier for me.  Thanks

Comment: @FredJ. Did you subscribe to `users` publication in the current template or parent templates or in `Meteor.startup`? Your publication is only returning current logged in user. But I think, you want to publish other users as well.

Comment: @Kishor I don't want all client to see all client using the console thus I am not happy to publish all client unless I am missing something. Please also note that my edit publish code is on the server as indicated

Comment: @FredJ. So are you checking for current user's username with `Meteor.users.findOne({username: username})` or other user's username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your publication is returning only current user, the client side got only one record, which is the currently logged in user's record. If you want to access other users, you might need to do something like this.

```
Meteor.publish('users', function () {
    if (this.userId) {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: { 'services': 0 } }); //to return all users.. you might have to limit the users based on your requirements.
    }
});
```

Once you have this publication, you might need to check whether you have subscribed to this publication in your current template or not. If you didn't subscribe to this, the subscribe to it like this,

```
Template.yourTemplate.onCreated(function () { //replace "yourTemplate" with your template name.
    this.subscribe('users');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to check whether the username already exists or not, you need to call a server method like this,

On server:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'checkIfUserExists': function (username) {
        return (Meteor.users.findOne({username: username})) ? true : false;
    }
});
```

On client:

```
if (Session.get('taskSelected') == 'login') {
    var username = inputDoc[0].value + '-' + inputDoc[1].value;
    Meteor.call('checkIfUserExists', username, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            alert('There is an error while checking username');
        } else {
            if (result === false) {
                alert('username not found.');
            } else {
                alert('A user with this username already exists..');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to find out if a user is currently registered or not, and if registered then log'm in if not then create account. Which I have it in place but wanted to first find if he/she is already registered hence my original question.

Comment: @FredJ. Updated the answer.